# Why this if Else program executes The Else part?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    if(a=0)
    {
        printf("No is wrong");
    }
    
    else printf("No is right");
    return 0;
}
```

i know it was given (a=0) inside if condition not (a==0) so why it is printing the Else part "No is right" ?

Comment: Because assignment returns assigned value

Answer (score 2):

Assignment returns the assigned value, so the statement `a = 0` returns `0`.
In C, `0` is evaluated as false so it skips to the else clause and prints "No is right".

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a to 0 in your if statement.

```
a = 0  # assignment
a == 0 # equality
```

So, to fix your code, change your if statement to `if (a == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You are currently missing "==" as you assign to an execution statement.
   Remember when you assign a variable you only use "=".
   However, when "asking" / "Checking a condition" you will need to use
   "==".

   Also, you need curly braces around the else statement for it to excicute.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0
```

This is an assignment operator. whenever you use '=' it assign the value of the right operand to the left operand.

For a condition we use '==' and check whether if it is true or not and evaluate the statement.

```
a=0   // a equals to 0 (assignment operator) //
a==0  // checking if a equals to 0 (comparison/relational operator) //
```